# How to retrieve specific members of a collection using Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am  wondering if there is any way to retrieve a record and specific number of its members of collection.

I have a class called MyGroup which keeps a list of Students, each student can be in one group at a time. I need to retrieve list of available students of each group. If I retrieve all the students of each group and find available ones it needs a big amount of memory to run a loop through the collection and check the available field of each student.

On the other hand, (Bidirectional) if I execute a select clause on students to retrieve those students that are available, in this way I am retrieving the group class record as well (since it is a member of student). So for each of students I am retrieving its fields + group's fields.

**Sample data**

```
Group 1
Name available
Jack  true
Luke  false
Nou   true
...

Group 2
Name available
Mike   false
George false
Alex   true
...
```

**Expected Result**

```
Name Available Group GroupName
Jack true       1     Wolfs
Nou  true       1     Wolfs
Alex true       2     Tigers
```

**Classes**

```
@Entity
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private boolean available;
    @OneToOne
    private MyGroup group;

    getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class MyGroup {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany
    private List<Student> student = new ArrayList();

    getters and setters
}
```

Comment: "if I execute a select clause on students to retrieve those students that are available I may end up executing inner selects for group records for many times as each student record has a group field in it."  What?

Comment: @Taylor I've rephrased it please let me know if it is readable now

Comment: Yes its possible based on search id of student and group id . If you use above entity of student and Mygroup u may get struck in Normal Forms .U will get redundant on stundent data.You are supposed to check minimizing redundant data in entity that would perfect design.

Comment: So whats your suggestion? I do not get that

Comment: `So for each of students I am retrieving its fields + group's fields.` Yes but hibernate will still generate one instance of Group for each group.  To be clear `someStudentInGroup1.getGroup() == someOtherStudentInGroup1.getGroup()`

Comment: @Taylor yes thats correct, so how to retrieve it in this way, and do I need to keep group as a member in student class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the hibernate by default lazy loading is true so if you are executing a select clause on the students table and fetching students so by default with one student object u will get the group id as the foreign key and i think not all the records of the associated group object will fetch atonce .If u want to fetch the list of students associated with the group object later u can do that but due to the lazy loading list of students associated with a group object will not fetch atonce .I think this is your major problem.You do not want to fetch the list of students associated with a group atonce.I think your current student table structure will be like this .

```
id name group_id
 1 jack  1
 2  joe  2
 3  Mack 1
```

if you can add one more field boolean available then your query can be more specific like the student which belong to a group id and avialble true.

```
Boolean available
```

now your student table structure will be like this.

```
id name group_id available
1   jack 1         true
2    Joe  2         true
3    Mack  1        false
```

so now u can query specific set of student based on available boolean field

Comment: what do you mean by adding available field ? I have this field in my student class, I want to retrieve all the students records that are in a group at once, I just remembered because of Lazy settings the group wont be retrieved all the time but there is another issue which is redundancy which I need to solve.

Comment: @J888 you are retrieving on the basis of available field only or on the base of available and group both if you are querying on the base of both then u will not get the redundant data

Comment: I just want to have a list of all students who's available field is true (but I need to know in which group they are so I need to retrieve the groups as well)

Comment: Just now I've provided the expected result, in the question.

Comment: @J888 you can use this hql according to your namings String hql="Select stu.name ,stu.available,stu.group,stu.group.name from Student stu where stu.available=true"

Comment: Since group also keep a list of students. Is  that fine to keep the group as a member of student class?

Comment: If you are making the group as a member of Student class then it will help u in the cascading operations .And i think if u will query from Student class then it is going to be more memory efficient query becuase if u will query from gruop then u will have to laod the student list iterate and check for avilability .Below is one link for the relation ships same as your's .So i think it is ok if you are making the relations hip bidirectional   http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42012/discussion-between-deepak-and-j888)